# How to place 2 divs next to each others with fixed position and 100% Height

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create 2 `div`s, one of them is the left sidebar and the other one is the body of the page where content shows up.  What I'm trying to do is:

- make the sidebar div height 100%
- the body height 100% too
- make the body's width change when sidebar width changes.

This is the code that I've tried so far:

```
#Sidebar{
  background-color:#F0F0F0;
  height: calc(100% - 80px);
  width: 257px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#content {
  margin: 0;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
}
```

when I do this, the content `div` shows IN the Sidebar!

```css
#Sidebar {
    height: calc(100% - 80px);
    width: 257px;
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
#content {
    margin: 0;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    border:1px solid tomato;
}
```

```html
<div id="Sidebar">
  Hello World!!
 </div>
<div id="content">
  Content Div
</div>
```

Note that i use Jquery .Resizable to change the width.
and this is a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/j64r3bm1/

Comment: Can you post your HTML markup as well? Might be an error in there causing the problem.

Comment: ive added a snippet.

Comment: Please add details on how you are changing the sidebar width.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add

```
left: 257px;
top: 0;
```

To the `#content` div and it will appear how you want it. To get this to resize, you'd adjust this. The alternative is to use a container, like this:

```css
#Container {
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

#Sidebar {
    height: calc(100% - 80px);
    width: 257px;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
#content {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    border:1px solid tomato;
}
```

```html
<div id="Container">
  <div id="Sidebar">
    Hello World!!
   </div>
  <div id="content">
    Content Div
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i made the sidebar resizable by the user using .resizable , jquery ui library thats why i want it like that.

Comment: @user3474108 I've updated my answer with more info and a very easy alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `margin-left` of your main content to the same width (+gap if you prefer) and change it when you resize your sidebar.

```
#content {
    margin-left: 257px;
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j64r3bm1/2/

---

To explain what's happening:  when you use `position:fixed`, it no longer takes up space and effectively 'hovers' on the page, so when your content div comes along, it gets put at left:0 because they're nothing to its left that's taking up space on the page.

You could also use `position:fixed` on your content and set the left - but then neither will take up 100% height (as they will both be 0width/0height).

Alternatively, you could take out the `position:fixed` and use `float:left`.

Comment: The sidebar still goes on the main content div when i change its width. :(

Comment: Did you also change the `margin-left` at the same time?  Neither your fiddle nor the question included *how* you change the sidebar width.

Comment: If you're using jquery.resizable then you'll need to hook into the `resize` event to also change the content width.   As this wasn't on your question, you should probably accept an answer and create a new question.  I removed the `jquery` tag as there was no mention of jquery in the question - it should also have jquery-ui tag.

Answer (score 0):

That is the Solution :

```js
var offsetHeight = document.getElementById('Sidebar').offsetHeight;
document.getElementById('content').style.height = offsetHeight+'px';
```

```css
#Sidebar{
background-color:#F0F0F0;
height: 700px;
width: 10%;
float:left;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
overflow: hidden;

}
#content {
margin: 0;
width:90%;
float:right;
background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<div id="Sidebar">
Side bar
</div>
<div id="content">
Hello World !
</div>
```

Comment: Are you asking?  Or providing an answer?  Questions should be as comment on the question.

Comment: not really, when i change the width of the sidebar, the main content div goes down.

Answer (score 0):

Can't You just put the sidebar

```
.sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100vh;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 275px;
}
```

and the body container

```
body {
    padding-left: 275px;
}
```

it will never overlap and you can just build your body as you wish.
The fun thing about this is when you use media-queries to handle mobile version - you can just remove padding and move sidebar outside of body and on some button (or anything) make it slide into view.

Comment: i made the sidebar resizable by the user using .resizable , jquery ui library thats why i want it like that...

Comment: Is there anything that does not allow you to catch resize event and then read new element width and apply it to body padding? I mean - there's no real way to set two fixed elements side by side automatically. Position fixed means that its fixed by name - it does not see any other elements.

Comment: thats exactly what i did, check the new post i made, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna give you an out there answer, I've tested this in firefox and chrome and it works. But it's a bit cutting edge so I'm not sure if IE will support it.

It's using css variables, if you have a different variable in at the start (in the :root section) then the page will be calculated differently.

I also took your borders out as they mess with total width and used background colours to tell the divs apart.

**EDIT:**

I've added a tiny amount of JS to show the variable being updated on the fly and everything readjusting.

```js
changeSidebar = function() {
  var customSize = document.querySelector('.sidebar-width').value;
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--menu-width', customSize + 'px');
}
```

```css
:root {
  --menu-width: 257px
}
#sidebar,
#sidebar-footer {
  width: var(--menu-width);
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed
}
body {
  margin: 0
}
#sidebar {
  height: calc(100% - 80px);
  top: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: orange
}
#sidebar-footer {
  height: 80px;
  top: calc(100% - 80px);
  background: pink
}
#content {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  width: calc(100% - var(--menu-width));
  height: 100%;
  background: tomato
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">
  Hello World!!
</div>
<div id="sidebar-footer">
  I'm just here to fill that space...
</div>
<div id="content">
  Content Div
  <br />
  <input class="sidebar-width" value='257'>
  <button onclick="changeSidebar();">Enter</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like i figured out how to do it. 
and I used JQuery to do that, all what i did is :

```
#Sidebarlist
{
    background-color: var(--SidebarBackgroundColor);
    height: calc(100% - 80px);
    color:var(--SidebarTextColor);
    width: 257px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
#MainContentdiv {
    height: 100%;
}
```

And using jquery :

```
$('#Sidebarlist').resizable({
       start: function( event, ui ) {},
       stop: function( event, ui ) {},
       handles: 'n,w,s,e',minWidth: 200,
       maxWidth: 400
});
$( "#Sidebarlist" ).on( "resizestart", function( event, ui ) {
     var marginleft = $("#Sidebarlist").width();
     $('#MainContentdiv').css('margin-left',marginleft);
});
$( "#Sidebarlist" ).on( "resizestop", function( event, ui ) {
    var marginleft = $("#Sidebarlist").width();
    $('#MainContentdiv').css('margin-left',marginleft);
});
```

Thanks for anybody that answered my question.

Comment: You probably want to hook into `resize` as well as per my previous comment.

Comment: TBH: This answers parts of the question that were *not in the question*.

Comment: Sorry, i thought it's possible to do with CSS and HTML only.